# Create sheet from Drupal module

Tags: drupal-7, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1

I'm working on a Drupal module to create a Smartsheet when a Drupal node, of a specific type, is published.

The sheet is being created fine but is not using the template I'm specifying with the formId variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Code is:

```
<?php

function smartsheet_node_insert($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'oa_space') {

    // Initialize URL Variables
    $baseURL = "https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1";
    $sheetsURL = $baseURL ."/sheets/";
    $columnURL = $baseURL. "/sheet/" . $node->nid . "/columns";

    // Insert your Smartsheet API Token here
    $accessToken = "[my api token]";

    // Create Headers Array for Curl
    $headers = array(
        "Authorization: Bearer ". $accessToken,
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    );


    // Create new sheet
    $theSheet = array(
      'name' => $node->title,
      'fromId' => '[template id]',
    );

    $postfields = json_encode($theSheet);

    // Connect to Smartsheet API
    $curlSession = curl_init($sheetsURL);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $createResponse = curl_exec($curlSession);

    // Assign response to PHP object
    $createObj = json_decode($createResponse);

    if (curl_getinfo($curlSession, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 200) {

    //if (curl_errno($curlSession)) {
        drupal_set_message("Oh No! Could not create sheet " . $node->title . "because " . $createObj->message);
    } else {
        // Tell the user!
        drupal_set_message("A Smartsheet has been created for the " . $node->title . " project");

        // close curlSession
        curl_close($curlSession);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good. If the sheet is being created, then the structure of your call is good. It's likely that you just have an incorrect templateId. Where did you get the template Id?

Through the Smartsheet interface, you can find the template Id in the [Sheet Properties](http://help.smartsheet.com/customer/portal/articles/1205389-sheet-properties). [This article](http://help.smartsheet.com/customer/portal/articles/1205389-sheet-properties) on the Smartsheet Help section describes where to find the Sheet Properties. In the properties window you'll take the value for Sheet ID, and use it for the `fromId` value in your Create Sheet call.

Comment: Hi,

Yes, I had the template ID correct, I copied it exactly as described in your linked article.

I still can't get it to work...

Comment: Does your new sheet have the same column names as the template, but the data from the template isn't there?

Comment: If you are still having trouble, please send us the template ID and the ID of a sheet you most recently created from that template using your code, at api@smartsheet.com - so we can help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

@stmcallister.  Exactly.  The sheet structure is copied but not the content.

Template ID = 2774566423553924, newest sheet ID = 8533387423049604.

Thanks,

Glenn